# Kivy app AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, kivy

i'm new into Kivy, i have a project that have many **sliders** for inputting a value.
so, after the result screen showed, there is a button that navigate to home screen then reset all sliders value to 0.
here's my main.py code

```
class result(Screen):
    g1 = NumericProperty(0)
    g2 = NumericProperty(0)
    g3 = NumericProperty(0)

    def homebtn(self):
        self.g1.value = 0
        self.g2.value = 0
        self.g3.value = 0
        sm.current = 'home'
```

then the error i got is:

```
File "/home/abrory7/PycharmProjects/penyakitPencernaan/main.py", line 765, in home
 self.g1.value = 0
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: When you wrote `self.g1.value`, `g1` is an instance variable, but you provided `g1 = NumericProperty(0)` as a class variable. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: Setting it with `self.g1 = 0` should be enough inside the class.

Comment: @Shivam Jha tried deleting the `g1 = NumericProperty(0)` line, but it returns `AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'g1'`

Comment: @TaufiqAbrory you should write `g1.value = 0` instead of `self.g1.value = 0)` in your `homebtn()` method

Comment: i updated what i found to the answers. referencing the screen where the sliders are with `get_screen()` worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign values directly to Property so this should work and keep them as property:

```
class result(Screen):
    g1 = NumericProperty(0)
    g2 = NumericProperty(0)
    g3 = NumericProperty(0)

    def homebtn(self):
        self.g1 = 0
        self.g2 = 0
        self.g3 = 0
        sm.current = 'home'
```

Comment: Thanks! the errors didn't show after i tried that, but the remain problem is slider value still didn't reset to 0

Comment: If that helped validate it as answers or else show your slider code if you want us to help

Answer (score 0):

so, i just trying some possibilities that i could try and i think i found how to solve my problem.
i tried referencing the screen name with `get_screen('screen_name')` like this:

```
class result(Screen):
    def homebtn(self):
        self.manager.get_screen('page1').g1.value = 0
        self.manager.get_screen('page2').g2.value = 0
        self.manager.get_screen('page3').g3.value = 0
        sm.current = 'home'
```

after i press the home button, the sliders values now resetting to 0